# how to convert time in string format into date time format using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have textbox that accepts time format like this 12:40 PM but would like to convert it into time format like this 12:40:00 basically without the PM or AM.  Here is what i have so far:

```
string StartTime = ((TextBox)TestDV.FindControl("txtBST")).Text.ToString();
```

thanks

Comment: try google for datetime formats in .net

Comment: DateTime.Parse or DateTime.TryParse methods.  Look them up.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx TimeSpan.Parse should do the trick

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh TimeSpan will not parse times with an AM/PM indicator.  It is for _durations_, not _times_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are bringing it in as a string this is actually kind of easy.

```
string StartTime = ((TextBox)TestDV.FindControl("txtBST")).Text.ToString();
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
try { dt = Convert.ToDateTime(StartTime); } 
catch(FormatException) { dt = Convert.ToDateTime("12:00 AM"); }
StartTime = dt.ToString("HH:mm");
```

So you bring in your string, and convert it to a date.  if the input is not a valid date, this will default it to 00:00.  Either way, it gives you a string and a DateTime object to work with depending on what else you need to do.  Both represent the same value, but the string will be in 24-Hour format.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 8):

One option would be to parse into a `DateTime` and then back to a string:

```
string s = "12:40 PM";

DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(s);

string s2 = dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss");  // 12:40:00
```

Be aware, however, that most operations work better with a `DateTime` versus a string representation of a `DateTime`.

Comment: I would personally steer clear of the generic `DateTime.Parse` - if the format is known, specify it!

Comment: Also, you mean `ss` at the end, not `mm`

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree - just getting the general idea across.

Answer (score 5):

First you should parse it to a `DateTime`, then format it. It sounds like your input format is something like `hh:mm tt` and your output format is `HH:mm:ss`. So, you'd have:

```
string input = "12:40 PM"
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "hh:mm tt",
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string output = dateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that:

- I've used `DateTime.ParseExact` which will throw an exception if the parsing fails; you *may* want to use `DateTime.TryParseExact` (it depends on your situation)
- I've used the invariant culture for both operations here. I don't know whether or not that's correct for your scenario.
- I've used `hh:mm`, but you *might* want `h:mm`... would you expect "1 PM" or "01 PM"?
- You don't parse seconds, so that part will always be 0... is that okay?